# Docker "cannot allocate memory" - virtual memory tuning

Tags: rhel, kernel, memory, docker, out-of-memory

We are building or running Docker containers in our Jenkins instances built on top of Centos7 within AWS EC2.
We have 2 instances of t2.medium boxes with 2 CPUs and 3.5 Gb of Available memory.
In once case we are building the containers in another we are just pulling them and running (different container).

We started to get errors

```
open /var/lib/docker/overlay/<sha>-init/merged/dev/console: cannot allocate memory
```

and in `journalctl` we get

```
page allocation failure: order:4
```

Running page cache dump resolves the issue for a while

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

So what I noticed that while running the docker task, `Dirty` memory block spikes (as it should) and `Mapped` jumps after it. However, the `DirectMap4k` is relatively close to that jump.

For example:
**Idle machine**

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep -P "(Dirty|Mapped|DirectMap4k)"
Dirty:               104 kB
Mapped:            45696 kB
DirectMap4k:      100352 kB
```

**Active Machine**

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep -P "(Dirty|Mapped|DirectMap4k)"
Dirty:             72428 kB
Mapped:            70192 kB
DirectMap4k:      100352 kB
```

So this machine takes some time to start failing, whereas identical machine reports `DirectMap4k: 77824 kB` and thus fails regularly (it also has to handle building more complex container), but `sysctl vm` is identical.

The underlying problem that build/boot of the docker container throws out of memory error and the question is what needs to be tuned for the kernel to make it stable.

---

Docker version

```
Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:20:36 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:21:56 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Kernel `3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64`

sysctl vm

```
vm.admin_reserve_kbytes = 8192
vm.block_dump = 0
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 10
vm.dirty_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 3000
vm.dirty_ratio = 30
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 500
vm.drop_caches = 1
vm.extfrag_threshold = 500
vm.hugepages_treat_as_movable = 0
vm.hugetlb_shm_group = 0
vm.laptop_mode = 0
vm.legacy_va_layout = 0
vm.lowmem_reserve_ratio = 256   256     32
vm.max_map_count = 65530
vm.memory_failure_early_kill = 0
vm.memory_failure_recovery = 1
vm.min_free_kbytes = 67584
vm.min_slab_ratio = 5
vm.min_unmapped_ratio = 1
vm.mmap_min_addr = 4096
vm.nr_hugepages = 0
vm.nr_hugepages_mempolicy = 0
vm.nr_overcommit_hugepages = 0
vm.nr_pdflush_threads = 0
vm.numa_zonelist_order = default
vm.oom_dump_tasks = 1
vm.oom_kill_allocating_task = 0
vm.overcommit_kbytes = 0
vm.overcommit_memory = 0
vm.overcommit_ratio = 50
vm.page-cluster = 3
vm.panic_on_oom = 0
vm.percpu_pagelist_fraction = 0
vm.stat_interval = 1
vm.swappiness = 30
vm.user_reserve_kbytes = 108990
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 100
vm.zone_reclaim_mode = 0
```

Answer (score 6):

## TL;DR

```
sudo su
sysctl -w vm.swappiness=10
```

## Explanation

I've created a testing scenario where I can reproduce this error 10/10 times. This is just building a larger image directly via command line rather than through CI.

as mentioned workaround I knew was

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

So I've tried to corelate it to `DirectMap` values. Since I learned that those values represent TLB load and cannot be tuned directly I've looked up the preference value to use them and that is swappiness.

[RHLE 7 Docs explain swappiness](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/sect-Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-Performance_Tuning_Guide-Configuration_tools-Configuring_system_memory_capacity.html#sect-Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-Performance_Tuning_Guide-Configuring_system_memory_capacity-Virtual_Memory_parameters):

> #### ⁠swappiness
>
> The swappiness value, ranging from 0 to 100, controls the degree to
>   which the system favors anonymous memory or the page cache. A high
>   value improves file-system performance while aggressively swapping
>   less active processes out of RAM. A low value avoids swapping
>   processes out of memory, which usually decreases latency at the cost
>   of I/O performance. The default value is 60.
>
> **WARNING**
>   Setting swappiness==0 will very aggressively avoids swapping out, which > increase the risk of OOM killing under strong memory and I/O pressure.

So reducing it lowers the reliance on memory cache pages. By default, EC2 Centos 7 Images that we use, set it to 30 so reducing it to 10 made the large image built successfully 10/10 times.

Comment: Hi, My swapiness is set to 10. still I get the same error. Should I decrease even more ? If so, upto which value can I decrease it ? Thanks :)

Comment: Also, I am using Centos and don't have swapping enabled.

Comment: Long story short - not sure. That's why I had removed this as an accepted answer. It might solve it, it might not. I've noticed that on our older systems eventually, it did not.